# Получить название файла из папки в Swift?

Tags: swift, test-automation

Занимаюсь автотестированием на XCUITest на MacOs, столкнулся с задачей: нужно получить названия всех файлов с определенным расширением (.pdf) в папке. Можно ли это как то сделать в XCUITest?  Если нет, то как это реализовать на Swift?

Comment: Как пример: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58955213/5479247

Comment: Тут возвращается URL файла, как просканировать папку и вернуть имена файлов с определенным расширением?

Comment: Там именно папка сканируется на предмет . m4a файлов.

Answer (score 0):

Вот к такому виду привел результат.

```
extension FileManager {
    
    class func directoryUrl() -> URL?
    {
        let documentsPath = "myUrlToFolder"
        let filesPath = URL(string: documentsPath)!
        return filesPath
    }
    
    class func allRecordedData() -> [String]? {
        if let documentsUrl = FileManager.directoryUrl() {
            do {
                let directoryContents = try FileManager.default.contentsOfDirectory(at: documentsUrl,                                           includingPropertiesForKeys: nil)
                let resultUrls = directoryContents.filter{ $0.pathExtension == "pdf" }
                let filesName = resultUrls.map {$0.lastPathComponent}
                print(filesName)
                return filesName
            } catch {
                return nil
            }
        }
        return nil
    }
}
```